# Write data not flushing for System.Net.HttpWebRequest Stream

Tags: json, powershell, windows-7, powershell-2.0

I've been trying to construct a simple HTTP request to post all process data in JSON format to a server with PowerShell 2.0, which I need to use out of necessity. Unfortunately, every time I execute my script on a Windows 7 OS, I notice that the **the JSON payload is cut off** (very frustrating). The actual payload is very large at around **74,100 bytes** in the request body. It is also probably useful to note that this request works successfully on a Windows Server 2012 machine, though I suspect that the payload request size for that particular OS is smaller.

Here is the code:

```
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($endpoint);
$request.ContentType = 'application/json';
$request.Method = 'POST';
$request.Headers.Add('Authorization', "Token " + $authToken);
$seconds = 1000;
$request.Timeout=3*$seconds;

$stringContentBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringContent);
$request.ContentLength = $stringContentBytes;  
$requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream();
$requestStream.Write($requestContentBytes, 0, $requestContentBytes.length);
$requestStream.Close();

$response = $request.GetResponse();
```

In this example `$endpoint` represents the target server endpoint, `$stringContent` represents the JSON-serialized payload that needs to be sent over the wire, and `authToken` is a string validation token.

I'm currently pointing `$endpoint` to a service called Request Bin, which very simply details the HTTP request information in a pretty, readable format. So, I know my server can't be causing the payload split.

Also, I've read through various posts about C# and PowerShell and they all mentioned this should be related to not closing the stream. However, as you can see in the code, I'm very clearly executing `$requestStream.Close()`, which from my research should be able to successfully flush the request stream.

Does anyone know why the output stream would not be processing all the JSON serialized information?

Comment: How about a `$requestStream.Flush()` before `.Close()`?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I just realized that the Request Bin service that I was using (in fact) was limiting the request body!